# JFrame adding Panels Components but not displaying them

Tags: java, swing

I'm using swing to create a kinda larger GUI that will pop up different frames that will act as editors based on the main frames buttons that have been pressed. This project was working yesterday and today I added code to classes that do not touch any of the existing code. Upon finishing some code i decided to run the program again to double check how I formatted the first editing window, but unbeknownst to me something has changed the way how the code executes and now upon hitting the Sprite editor button, the panel that pops up is blank. This panel only is visually blank however, as it has the 19 components that it originally had, as I can see my mouse changing to the text pointer in Text boxes and debug statements show that it has 19 components when I call getComponents().length. My code structure at the moment is a little large but the flow of code is something like this.

Class Main Panel renders fine and upon a button press it calls this

```
if(e.getSource() == resourceButton)
{           
    Utils.windowFromPanel(new SpriteEditor(), "SpriteEditor");
}
```

Which is a function that looks like this.

```
public static JFrame windowFromPanel(JPanel panel, String title)
{
    JFrame newWindow = new JFrame(title);

    newWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    newWindow.getContentPane().add( panel );
    newWindow.pack();
    newWindow.setVisible(true); 

    //returning it so we can control when it closes in other parts of the program
    return newWindow;
}
```

The return is so that other classes that use this function can call dispose() on the frame, but in this case i want to allow as many editors to be open as a user wants.

The constructor for SpriteEditor calls its parents constructor that looks like this.

```
public EditorObject()
{
    objectAsStrings = null;
    displayPanel = null;
    makeEditorPanel();
}
```

Where makeEditorPanel() is an abstract function that creates the panel, because EditorObject extends JPanel. This is what SpriteEditor's makeEditorPanel() looks like (sorry for the length).

```
public void makeEditorPanel() 
{
    setLayout( new GridBagLayout() );
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    filePath = new String();
    resourceName = new String();
    spriteName = new String();
    resourceField = new JTextField("Use . instead of slashes when typing in the path");
    openResourceTable = new JButton("Open");
    cropButton = new JButton("Select Cropping from picture");
    previewButton = new JButton("Preview Sprite");
    addSpriteButton = new JButton("Add Sprite");
    addResourceButton = new JButton("Add Resource");
    resourceNameField = new JTextField("Name");
    xStartField = new JTextField("0");
    yStartField = new JTextField("0");
    widthField = new JTextField("0");
    heightField = new JTextField("0");
    spriteNameField = new JTextField("Name1");
    displayPanel = new JPanel();

    resourceField.addActionListener(this);
    openResourceTable.addActionListener(this);
    addResourceButton.addActionListener(this);
    cropButton.addActionListener(this);
    previewButton.addActionListener(this);
    addSpriteButton.addActionListener(this);
    xStartField.addActionListener(this);
    yStartField.addActionListener(this);
    widthField.addActionListener(this);
    heightField.addActionListener(this);
    resourceNameField.addActionListener(this);
    spriteNameField.addActionListener(this);


    //formating of each element in this panel
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weighty = 0.0;
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.insets = new Insets(10, 20, 10, 20);
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    add(new JLabel("Resource Path"), c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridwidth = 2;
    c.ipadx = 120;
    add(resourceField, c);

    c.gridx = 3;
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    c.ipadx = 0;
    add(openResourceTable, c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    add(new JLabel("Resource Name"), c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    add(resourceNameField, c);

    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridwidth = 2;
    add(addResourceButton, c);

    c.gridy = 2;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridwidth = 2;
    c.weighty = 1;
    add(cropButton, c);

    c.gridy = 3;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    c.weighty = 0;
    add(new JLabel("xStart pixel"), c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    add(xStartField, c);

    c.gridx = 2;
    add(new JLabel("ystart pixel"), c);

    c.gridx = 3;
    add(yStartField, c);

    c.gridy = 4;
    c.gridx = 0;
    add(new JLabel("width in pixels"), c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    add(widthField, c);

    c.gridx = 2;
    add(new JLabel("height in pixels"), c);

    c.gridx = 3;
    add(heightField, c);

    c.gridy = 5;
    c.gridx = 1;
    add(new JLabel("Sprite Name"), c);

    c.gridx = 2;
    add(spriteNameField, c);

    c.gridy = 6;
    c.gridx = 0; 
    c.insets = new Insets(5, 10, 5, 10);
    c.gridwidth = 2;
    add( previewButton, c );

    c.gridx = 2; 
    add(addSpriteButton, c);

    updateButtons();
    addTextFieldListeners();
}
```

Some debugging I have done shows that even when i comment out all of this, and just do a add(new JLabel("testing")); still nothing renders in the new JFrame. Furthermore when I skip the Utils function and just have my main function initially render a SpriteEditor object rather than the main Panel the same behavior appears.

This behavior persists even after calling repaint(); revalidate();
I am at my wits end with this any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT

After more googling it turns out that the problem comes from calling the Accessor Methods in the Sprite Editor Class in other classes. For some reason, eclipse will not render a window if the fields can be changed in other parts of the code. https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/627683/ Tries to explain it but i dont fully understand. Ill post a full answer if I find out why that is.

TL DR: Getter and Setter functions that affect things like JTextFields will stop eclipse from rending them correctly.

Comment: When you add components to a panel in a visible GUI you must revalidate() and repaint() the panel.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: I do call revalidate and repaint() camickr.

Comment: Sorry MadProgrammer, i probably should have done this too, but i found the error is with eclipse and not with the code.